# Android Tabhost keyboard overlaps inputs

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tabhost

I have tabhost layout where i load my Form Activity(10 inputs in scroll bar). When i start typing on the  most bottom inputs, the keyboard shown and the focused input is not shown(the keyboard overlaps the inputs instead of scrolling as normal) and i can't see what am i my typing. When i tried to run the form activity outside tabhost, everything works as normal, i can type and see the inputs focused always. My min API level is 10, max is 17.

Any help or direction highly appreciated.

TabHost Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/layTab"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:background="#00A99D"
       android:paddingLeft="0dip"
       android:paddingRight="0dip" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"                
            android:padding="0dip" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/layTab"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Form Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">   
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="1"
            android:ems="10" />

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="2"
            android:ems="10" />             

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="3"
            android:ems="10" />    

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="4"
            android:ems="10" />    

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="5"
            android:ems="10" />    

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="6"
            android:ems="10" />    

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="7"
            android:ems="10" />    

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="8"
            android:ems="10" />    

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:hint="9"
            android:ems="10"/>



               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="10"
            android:ems="10" />    

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a keyboard pops up, it has 'two visual modes'. FullScreen, meaning that the window in which the keyboard renders is fully overlaying your application or not fullscreen.

In the second case the window, in which your activity displays, is resized. With this resizing, I assume that a `TabHost` does scale up but the child layouts (in the case your form) are not scaled the same way as if they would be a stand-alone layout.

The Android documentation states that an application using an EditText should be aware of:

- Properly set the inputType in your editable text views, so that the
  input method will have enough context to help the user in entering
  text into them.
- **Deal well with losing screen space when the input
  method is displayed. Ideally an application should handle its window
  being resized smaller, but it can rely on the system performing
  panning of the window if needed. You should set the
  windowSoftInputMode attribute on your activity or the corresponding
  values on windows you create to help the system determine whether to
  pan or resize (it will try to determine this automatically but may
  get it wrong).**
- You can also control the preferred soft input state
  (open, closed, etc) for your window using the same
  windowSoftInputMode attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I tried to set windowSoftInputMode to all possible values, but it did not work.